# How to create a domain data grid in Payara Server with domain discovery mode?

Tags: java, hazelcast, payara

I want to create a [Domain Data Grid](https://docs.payara.fish/documentation/payara-server/hazelcast/) in Payara Server 5.191 with [Domain Discovery Mode](https://docs.payara.fish/documentation/payara-server/hazelcast/discovery.html), where each node discovers each other by knowing the node IP address and port. According to the [documentation](https://docs.payara.fish/documentation/payara-server/hazelcast/discovery.html), the nodes are configured in the `domain.xml`. However, I couldn't find anything on how to exactly specify the nodes in the `domain.xml`. What is the name of the configuration option, where the nodes are specified?

Answer (score 0):

**It is similar to Glassfish.**

Create it in the Windows Operating System

1. You must download the application server. [enter link description here](https://www.payara.fish/documentation/getting-started-with-payara/You%20must%20download%20the%20application%20server)

when installed a directory is created

C:\Payara_Server

[image]

C:\Payara_Server\bin

[image]

We open shell command window 
and inside the command window

- C:\Payara_Server\bin ./asadmin
- `asadmin> create-domain --adminport 4848 domain1
  Enter admin user name[Enter to accept default]>
  Using port 4848 for Admin.
  Default port 8080 for HTTP Instance is in use. Using 1161
  Using default port 7676 for JMS.
  Using default port 3700 for IIOP.
  Using default port 8081 for HTTP_SSL.
  Using default port 3820 for IIOP_SSL.
  Using default port 3920 for IIOP_MUTUALAUTH.
  Default port 8686 for JMX_ADMIN is in use. Using 1162
  Distinguished Name of the self-signed X.509 Server Certificate is:
  [CN=moonbeam.gateway.2wire.net,OU=GlassFish,O=Oracle Corp.,L=Redwood Shores,ST
  California,C=US]
  Domain domain1 created.
  Command create-domain executed successfully.`
- `C:\Payara_Server\glassfish\domains\domain1` created
- Start the server
- `asadmin> start-domain domain1`
- link it with IDE NETBEANS

[image]

Comment: upvoted to offset the egregious and unnecessary down-vote. Few answers are perfect, but there's nothing about this answer that is deserving of a down-vote